# What are these constraints in competitive programming?

Tags: constraint-programming

[[image]

I wonder what is the significance of these constraints in CP problem. What is this subtask #1 and #2 and how are these important?

Comment: The task probably explain what those letters mean ("Alice has `N` apples" or something). They don't have any inherent meaning otherwise.

Comment: Where did you *get* those constraints, and what does *that* source say of their significance ?

Comment: This sounds like something you should ask your teacher. But CP problems are basically always much easier with more constraints.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure if the tag constraint programming is suitable, but neither C or C++ is so...

Comment: The constraints say what you can assume about the inputs. They tell you how many and how large problems you need to handle. You do not need to verify them; they are guarantees. The first subtask is simpler because N can only be 2 or 3.

Comment: @klutt these constraints are of a cp problem but as you can see the second line says 2≤N≤8 but then in subtask 2 they say N≤3. This is where confusion arises. Which constraint is to consider?

Comment: That means that 2≤N≤3. What's unclear?

Comment: @klutt I was confused seeing two different constraints on N. One says N is between 2 & 8 and other says N is less than 3.

Comment: @AnishVijay 2≤N≤3 => 2≤N≤8

Comment: Or another way to see it: N≤3 AND 2≤N≤8 <=> 2≤N≤3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an incomplete problem description, there is simply no way to be sure what this is about.

**However** if this is all you have access to right now and if every minute counts, here is what you can try to guess:

`T` is usually a letter assigned to the number of test cases that your program will be tested against. It is guaranteed to be from `1` and `2000` inclusive.

A test case is delimited by all the variables needed for your program to solve the problem. `N` is a number from 2 to 8 inclusive. `X` is an array of positive integers of length `N`.

It is also guaranteed that `X` is sorted in an ascending fashion.

This will only help you to `parse` the input, and maybe get an idea of what conclusion you may come to.

I hope you have more info about this problem, otherwise you won't be able to solve it. Good luck

If your program manages to solve for any `N` from 2 to 3 inclusive, you get 10% of the maximum score.

If your program solve all values for `N` from 2 to 8 you get 90% of the score + since it also solves subtask #1 you get 100% of the maximum score.

Answer (score 2):

Constraints tell you the upper and lower limit of inputs coming in. For eg. 1 <= T <=2000
would mean that the input for T would be between 1 and 2000. I am guessing you are on codechef. Subtasks allow points to be earned even if your code can't solve the problem with the original constraints. For eg. For an upper limit of n at 3, the code would take lesser time than it would for an upper limit of 8. So even if your code is not optimized enough to deal with the original constraint, you still earn some points and know that your code works, all that needs to be done is optimization.

Comment: Ya it's a codechef problem. It means the subtasks doesn't matter much if my code is working with original constraints. Right?

Comment: Yes, they don't.